# REST API implementation using Java Core

Tags: java, rest

Now I am learning the development of REST API using Spring MVC, Spring Boot. And when I am learning the different API development framework, I found that Jersey is also used a lot among the developer community. And also found that can develop using core Java through the implementation of SOA Architecture.

I have these questions:

- Here my doubt is that how smooth core Java for implementing REST APIs. Is the core Java developer using same methodology that the Spring Boot developer uses?
- What is the comparison point of Core Java and Spring MVC for developing ReST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Spring stack, I can suggest using Spring REST for REST.
In fact, it is built on the top of Spring MVC.

Please feel free to ask any specific questions.

Comment: I am tried and developed my project microservices using spring MVC, spring boot , maven , spring cloud (Eureka,Zuul,Hystrix,Ribbon). When I am exploring ReST using core java, I found can build using java 8. That's why I shared my doubt. Which is most using,current approach is by using spring boot , Spring mvc and spring cloud.Can I follow these technical stack?

Comment: Ok Sir, Thank you for your response.